# SQLPLUS returns no Data when use multiple join

Tags: sql, oracle11g, oracle-sqldeveloper, sqlplus

I am running into a very weird situation. 
I have two Oracle XE Installations.

One is installed in a Spanish Language Windows machine another one in English windows machine.

I have a SQL query to run on the Spanish system. This SQL has many joins. When I execute that SQL using SQLPLUS, I get no data which is of Integer or Long Data type.

I was scared because I can visualize that there is data in tables which must appear in result of the query. Thus, I exported the schema into my English system. And ran the same SQL query using SQLPLUS. And I got expected results with many data.

There is no issue with my SQL. This SQL being used for a very long time in my project.

The query looks like--

```
SELECT
           device_id,
           SUM(COALESCE(total_page_volume,
           0)) AS total_page_volume,
           SUM(COALESCE(total_page_volume,
           0)-COALESCE(color_page_volume,
           0)) AS mono_page_volume,
           SUM(COALESCE(color_page_volume,
           0)) AS color_page_volume,
           SUM(COALESCE(total_page_volume,
           0)) as totalvolume,
           SUM(COALESCE(color_page_volume,
           0)) as colorvolume,
           SUM(COALESCE(total_page_volume,
           0)-COALESCE(color_page_volume,
           0)) as monovolume,
           SUM(COALESCE(print_volume,
           0)) AS print_volume,
           SUM(COALESCE(copy_volume,
           0)) AS copy_volume,
           SUM(COALESCE(fax_volume,
           0)) AS fax_volume,
           SUM(COALESCE(total_oversize_volume,
           0)) AS total_oversize_volume,
           SUM(COALESCE(total_duplex_volume,
           0)) AS total_duplex_volume,
           SUM(COALESCE(num_detected_error_states,
           0)) AS num_detected_error_states,
           SUM(COALESCE(num_device_status,
           0)) AS num_device_status,
           SUM(COALESCE(num_printer_status,
           0)) AS num_printer_status,
           MIN(start_time) as minday,
           MAX(end_time) as maxday 
        FROM
           device_data_summary,
           group_membership g_m ,
           group_closure g_c 
        WHERE
           g_m.entity_id=device_id 
           AND g_c.child_id=g_m.group_id 
           AND g_c.parent_id = 95 
           AND CAST(start_time AS TIMESTAMP )  >=  CAST(TO_CHAR(g_m.start_date,'DD-MON-YYYY') AS TIMESTAMP) 
           AND (
              (
                 g_m.end_date is NULL
              ) 
              or (
                 CAST(end_time AS TIMESTAMP) <= CAST(g_m.end_date AS TIMESTAMP)
              )
           ) 
           AND start_time>=to_timestamp('2016-07-25 00:00:00','YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS')  
           AND end_time<=to_timestamp('2016-08-24 23:59:59','YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS')  
           AND period=1  
        GROUP BY
           device_id;
```

Comment: Without seeing code, I would guess that you have some implicit data type conversions that are behaving differently depending on your session's NLS settings.  WIthout code that reproduces the problem, though, I would expect this question to be closed.

Comment: Any thought which Data type can have such issues. ?

Comment: Strings, dates, and numbers would all potentially convert differently to and from each other.  And that assumes that the issue isn't that you have data in a different character set in the two systems (i.e. the Spanish system has a string "León" that gets converted to "Leon" when you import into an English system using the US7ASCII character set).

Comment: Please [edit] your question add the `create table` statements for the tables in question, the query you are using and the output you get.  _Formatted_ text please, [no screen shots](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-may-i-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557)

Comment: The table DDL would still be useful; it would tell us, for example, what data types the `start_date`, `start_time` etc. columns are, and whether the conversions and casts are necessary or could be breaking something. The `CAST(TO_CHAR(g_m.start_date,'DD-MON-YYYY') AS TIMESTAMP)` looks suspicious though. What is the `NLS_DATE_FORMAT`, `NLS_DATE_LANGUAGE` and `NLS_TIMESTAMP_FORMAT` in your sessions against each database?

Comment: `CAST(TO_CHAR(g_m.start_date,'DD-MON-YYYY') AS TIMESTAMP)` makes no sense at all if `start_date` is already a `date` or `timestamp`

Answer (score 1):

You are relying on implicit conversion in at least this part of your query:

```
... >=  CAST(TO_CHAR(g_m.start_date,'DD-MON-YYYY') AS TIMESTAMP)
```

Your are converting the `start_date` to a string, and then casting that string to a timestamp, which has to rely on the session's `NLS_TIMSTAMP_FORMAT` setting. Different values for that might produce correct results, an error, or incorrect results. For example these two formats do what you expect:

```
alter session set nls_timestamp_format = 'DD-MON-YYYY HH24:MI:SS';
select CAST(TO_CHAR(sysdate,'DD-MON-YYYY') AS TIMESTAMP) from dual;

25-AUG-2016 00:00:00                           

alter session set nls_timestamp_format = 'DD/MM/RRRR HH24:MI:SS';
select CAST(TO_CHAR(sysdate,'DD-MON-YYYY') AS TIMESTAMP) from dual;

25/08/2016 00:00:00
```

But these all give the wrong results; the first one ends up in the year 0025 (so you don't have that, otherwise *all* your data would match that condition):

```
alter session set nls_timestamp_format = 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS';
select CAST(TO_CHAR(sysdate,'DD-MON-YYYY') AS TIMESTAMP) from dual;

0025-08-20 16:00:00
```

and these two make the year 2020:

```
alter session set nls_timestamp_format = 'DD-MON-RR HH24:MI:SS';
select CAST(TO_CHAR(sysdate,'DD-MON-YYYY') AS TIMESTAMP) as nls,
  to_char(CAST(TO_CHAR(sysdate,'DD-MON-YYYY') AS TIMESTAMP), 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS') as formatted
from dual;

NLS                FORMATTED         
------------------ -------------------
25-AUG-20 16:00:00 2020-08-25 16:00:00

alter session set nls_timestamp_format = 'DD/MM/RR HH24:MI:SS';
select CAST(TO_CHAR(sysdate,'DD-MON-YYYY') AS TIMESTAMP) as nls,
  to_char(CAST(TO_CHAR(sysdate,'DD-MON-YYYY') AS TIMESTAMP), 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS') as formatted
from dual;

NLS               FORMATTED         
----------------- -------------------
25/08/20 16:00:00 2020-08-25 16:00:00
```

Presumably the session you get no results in is using a format model that produces a 2020 date, and and you have nothing that far in the future. You can change the NLS setting in your Spanish setting to show that a different value does then produce the results you expect.

You should not rely on implicit conversion or NLS settings. You probably don't really want to converting to a string at all here, as you don't do that anywhere else; perhaps the `start_date` has a time component you're trying to ignore by bouncing through a format with no time part, but in that case you could do:

```
CAST(TRUNC(g_m.start_date) AS TIMESTAMP)
```

... which leaves the value as a date not a string and doesn't require any implicit conversion.

I'm not sure why you're casting everything to timestamps to compare them anyway, but you haven't shown whether any of the columns are actually timestamps rather than dates. You seem to be doing it inconsistently anyway.